# Risk in connecting wrong ssh host?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, ssh-host-key

I've a ssh host key login setup in a remote server, for some reason, the DNS of that host is mapped to another server.

So assume the mistaken host cannot be trusted, should I change my key?

Answer (score 8):

When you connect to the wrong server, this should trigger a very noticeable client-side warning, because the server appears to use a key distinct from the key it was using in previous sessions. The client remembers servers' keys. For a classic [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) client, the warning looks like this:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
```

Of course, this relies on your client having already connected at least once to the right server; otherwise, the client will not know the right server key in advance.

Assuming that you *did* "click through" the warning (i.e. modified your `.ssh/known_hosts` to bypass it), then you connected to the wrong server. When using key-based authentication, the client computes a [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) on a string which contains the "key exchange hash", a session-specific value obtained from the key exchange mechanism through a hash function; the server verifies the signature with regards to the expected client's public key (in `.ssh/authorized_keys`).

In no way is the client's private key ever revealed to the server. Moreover, inclusion of the key exchange hash in that which is signed prevents the receiving server (the wrong/fake one) from reusing the signature to impersonate the user on the right server. Therefore, your client private key is safe; there is no need to change it.

(The key-based client authentication mechanism is described in [section 7 of RFC 4252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-7).)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I did exactly what you said, connected the wrong server and accepted the warning with a second mistake. So in short, you say I am still safe and my private key is not shared at all?

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried that you leaked your private key, at no point your private key is sent to the other server. As Thomas explains in his answer [How does ssh public key authentication work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23227/how-does-ssh-public-key-authentication-work):

> The core concept remains the same: the client proves its control of
>   the private key by performing an operation which requires knowledge of
>   that key, but such that the "inverse" operation can be done with the
>   public key which is located in the .ssh/authorized_keys on the server.